# SQL Server Update DateTime type to null

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, dbnull

Since it's friday my brain must have malfunctioned.

I'm trying to **update** a column of the type DateTime with the good ol' OleDb, the update always run (changing other column values on the same row) but for some reason the DateTime column refuses to be set to null.

Ofc the column allows null.

I'm using the OleDbParameter constructor to add a new parameter to my command might it be the parameter that refuses to run if the value is null?

I've tried SqlDateTime.Null, DbNull.Value and null as the parameter but nothing sets the value to null, it leaves it untouched or sets it to our beloved 1900-00-01.

any tips and tricks are appreciated

Comment: Does the column allow `NULL`s?

Comment: Post your code.  **DateTime** unless you use **DateTime?** cannot be **null.**  Of course if your variable cannot be **DateTime?** for some reason, set it an invalid value ( i.e. 1909 ), and if its set to that year manually set it to **NULL**

Comment: Can you show the actual update command? Do you have some guard `where` clause, or something else that will be doing a comparison with the parameter (and failing because `null`=/=`null`)

Comment: Ramhound "and if its set to that year manually set it to NULL" that's exactly what I'm looking for, but how the eff do I do it? The database just seems to swallow my DbNull and all the null values I've found so far.
@Damien_The_Unbeliever It's a regular "UPDATE tableX
SET    UserName = ?
WHERE  User_Id = 1  "

Nothing fancy at all I'll try to get a more hands on approach later on, the whole update runs and works perfectly just that it won't touch my DateTime Column. Anyway thanks for responding

Comment: I'd try posting the code anyway if I were you. If it were particularly clever you'd probably have solved it yourself by now. It could be precisely because it's the sort of code you consider "regular" that you aren't seeing where it's going awry.

Comment: Okay, apparently one should not cheat and use the constructor in a OleDbParameter. That apparently may or may not give you really odd problem.. 

I.E don't try to save a line of code just because you can kids..

anyway thank you for your help and support. I will never ever go to pizza hut on a friday again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want to use DBNull.Value

just like the prior comments you could do something like `DateTime? myDate = null;`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that unless you take specific action, a DateTime is going to be represented as DateTime.MinValue. So if you want a null in the DB, you will need to test the value and, if MinValue, send DBNull instead.

We actually use a method to get the value as date time or null if date is minvalue:

```
function object DateToDB(DateTime testDate) 
{
    if (testDate == DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        return DBNull.Value;
    } else 
    {
        return testDate;
    }
}
```

This method is then used to assign the parameter value.

Comment: I'm sorry if I come of harsh here, but the what does this have to do with the OleDbCommand? I'm already trying to set the parameter value to null but it won't Update the database value to null, it works perfectly fine when doing a Insert.

Comment: @ThomasLindvall: Sorry, I should have been more clear: this is the code that you use to set the OleDbCommand parameter value. You want to send DBNull.Value in the parameter instead of null. This method allows you to have a single location to perform this logic.